# Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: TypeError: $(...).calendar is not a function

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui

I am trying to use this npm package ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar ) with Meteor, but getting this error in the browser console:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: TypeError: $(...).calendar
>   is not a function

I tried following installation to fix this error:

```
npm i semantic-ui-calendar
npm semantic-ui-calendar --save
meteor npm i semantic-ui-calendar
meteor npm semantic-ui-calendar --save
```

My code:

**blaze-html-template:**

```
<template name="myTemplate">    
  <h3>Date only</h3>
  <div class="ui calendar" id="example2">
    <div class="ui input left icon">
      <i class="calendar icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</template>
```

**js-template-file:**

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example2').calendar({
          type: 'date'
        });
    });
});
```

Also moved this JQuery code from onRendered to helpers - without success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
npm install --save semantic-ui-calendar
```

And then import the files from the package by putting the following at the top of your file.

```
import { ... } from 'semantic-ui-calendar'
```

Comment: With `import { ... } from 'semantic-ui-calendar';` I get _"Unexpected token (2:9)"_ because of `{ ... }` . I changed `{ ... }` to `{ Calendar }`: `import { Calendar } from 'semantic-ui-calendar';` and I am getting now _"Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'semantic-ui-calendar'(…)"_